# Pushing docker image to Docker Hub from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dockerhub, docker-image

I have a .Net core web application with a Dockerfile.

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline to build the docker image, and want to push that image on Docker Hub.

But when I run the pipeline, it fails while pushing image with below error:

```
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2332684Z ##[section]Starting: Push an image
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2340807Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2340932Z Task         : Docker
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2341017Z Description  : Build, tag, push, or run Docker images, or run a Docker command
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2341132Z Version      : 0.154.1
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2341206Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2341308Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker
2019-07-25T07:40:39.2341405Z ==============================================================================
2019-07-25T07:40:39.4058071Z e6868ba4-0951-4724-b13b-58e178dacb79 exists true
2019-07-25T07:40:39.5494209Z [command]/usr/bin/docker push dockerDemo2019:19
2019-07-25T07:40:39.5780069Z The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/dockerDemo2019]
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5429692Z b0f339cf7b16: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5430778Z a385a9a129e2: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5431098Z 6339615de93e: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5431279Z c6c9de941dfa: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5431433Z 9c894eb0930b: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5431696Z d56055da3352: Preparing
2019-07-25T07:40:40.5431855Z d56055da3352: Waiting
2019-07-25T07:40:42.4737943Z denied: requested access to the resource is denied
2019-07-25T07:40:42.4880225Z ##[error]denied: requested access to the resource is denied
2019-07-25T07:40:42.4932585Z ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
2019-07-25T07:40:42.4960825Z ##[section]Finishing: Push an image
```

My pipeline setup:

[image]

I have verified Dockerregistry service connection and it is connected with dockerhub credential.

Comment: In the Docker task version switch it to version 2.* (I think you are in 0.*)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: you were correct, After changing it to `2.0*`, build was successfull, but with warning `No repository is specified. Nothing will be pushed.`

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to switch the Docker task version from `0.*` to `2.*`.

Then you need to define also your Docker hub repository name:

[image]

[image]

The same thing you need to do also in the `build` step - switch to `2.*` and define the repository name.

By the way - in the `2.*` version, the action name is `buildAndPush`, which combines both the build and push tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much. Azure documentation is really poor on this. Cheers!

Comment: Strange. I followed the steps but have a different error .

Comment: Strange. I followed the steps but have a different error . The last few lines from the log. Will be of great help if I could get this sorted . I can see the image is built however the last line Im getting a 404 error which I presume is being returned by Docker hub . Not sure why

Comment: @RajeshRajamani maybe it for a new question :)

Comment: What if I only want to push the image? How do I specify which image will be pushed?

Answer (score 1):

My Service Connection was the issue in my case . I messed it up as the default was "Others" .

After setting the Registry Type to DockerHub and subsequently setting up credentials , it worked fine .

Ofcourse the steps suggested by [![https://stackoverflow.com/users/7409220/shayki-abramczyk] were important too .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have setup the service connection for dockerhub and az pipelines (goto project settings-> service connections--> New service connection --> choose "Docker Registry" --> fill the required details there) in order to push the image to docker hub from az-pipelines directly.
2. Once you create service connection, move to configure the pipeline and edit the pipeline--> click on "show assistant" which is located at top-right under 'save and run' button.[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/capcR.png)
3. Here, search "docker push". It will display 'Docker' and 'Docker compose' --> select 'Docker' [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLPp.png)--> choose the service connection in place of 'container registry' which was configured earlier for the docker registry --> 'container repository' this is the place where we need to mention the "<yourDockerrepositoryName/imageName>" properly in this format [please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0hcC.png). Otherwise you will face  the error like "requested access to the resource is denied".

Hope this will be helpful! and have a great day!...Thank you.